# Get detailed data with filtered find result

Tags: regex, bash, unix, find, ls

I need to get a detailed list of all the files ending with "dcc" so I used this:

```
find . -regex '.*\.dcc$'
```

And it worked. But as I wrote I need a detailed list just like with `ls -l` so I used this:

```
find . -ls -regex '.*\.dcc$'
```

But that's showing me all the files in the directory.

I managed to overcome this problem with

```
ls -l `find . -regex '.*\.dcc$'`
```

But I'm interested to know what was wrong with this:

```
find . -ls -regex '.*\.dcc$'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering is important:

```
find . -regex '.*\.dcc$' -ls
```

Comment: Crap, you are right. That's why I hate `unix` so much! Thanks!

Comment: *why I hate `unix` so much* - On behalf of GNU findutils, "Ouch". The arguments to `find` can form complex expressions by combining filter and operation terms, this would not be possible without ordering having significance.